# Move dynamic explorer context menu entries into a cascading sub-menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry, context-menu

In the explorer context menu, static entries (that is, entries that are using shell rather than shellex in the registry), can be put into cascading sub-menus with only some registry-tweaking:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127467(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127431(v=vs.85).aspx

My context menu has a lot of dynamic shell-extensions that I only use occasionally, and I'd like to put all of these into a submenu ('Tools' for instance). But doing this with the registry seems to only work for static entries. Putting dynamic entries in the sub-menus using various methods always just prevents the sub-menu from opening.

How can this be accomplished short of writing a proxy shell-extension that manages the ones in the submenu?